# Databricks - Connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and Blob Storage - Sas Token on a Directory Level

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have been following this guide [Connect to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and Blob Storage - Sas Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/storage/azure-storage#sastokens)

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS") 

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider") 

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>", key="<sas-token-key>"))
```

It is then possible to read the files

```
spark.read.load("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>")
```

and list the files

```
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>")
```

And it works fine when I create the SAS Token on a container level. However, I would like to create the SAS token on a directory level instead.

Listing the files work as previously, but I can no longer read the files. It gives this error

[image]

Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant the necessary permissions for that.

Below are the available permissions while generating a SAS token at the directory level. By default, it will be only **Read**.

[image]

You need to grant **Read** and **List** permissions.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container>@<storage_acc>.dfs.core.windows.net/sample/")
```

Output:

```
[FileInfo(path='abfss://<container>@<storage_acc>.dfs.core.windows.net/sample/source1_data_preview (1).csv', name='source1_data_preview (1).csv', size=148, modificationTime=1702964218000)]
```

```
spark.read.csv("abfss://<container>@<storage_acc>.dfs.core.windows.net/sample/").head(2)
```

Output:

```
[Row(_c0='ID', _c1='Start Date (BST)', _c2='Value'), 
Row(_c0='3', _c1='2022-09-20T09:10:22.987654', _c2='200')]
```

To create SAS token :

[image]

Check below for give access to sub-folders and sub-files while creating SAS token.

[image]

Comment: I gave the read & list permission (saved as a access policy) when I tried it on a directory and it did not work. But interesting that you managed to get it working, then I know it should be possible. Many thanks!

Comment: first you list the files using dbutils and go for loading data.

Comment: And check if you are granting permission only on directory or sub-folders and sub-files.

Comment: Listing the directory and the subdirectories with dbutils works fine. However, when I want to read the files I get the "Server failed to authenticate the request" error. It is only when I create the SAS token on a container level it works.

Comment: What is the error code you are getting? is it 403 ? Add the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Yep the boring 403 code with the error in the screenshot I added above. Still quite strange why it works for you but not for me.

Comment: This is due to accessing different folder other than the folder you have sas token.

Comment: I have added screenshot for creating sas token for particular folder.

Comment: This error comes even if you given permission to that folder only but not for sub-files and directory. That would list the files but doesn't have access to read. kindly check it.